# DLL initialization error while trying to connect to Teradata with Python

Tags: python, teradata

I’ve been using Python’s teradatasql library to query Teradata, and just started getting a DLL initialization error with code that had previously been working.

This is the precise error:
`OSError: [WinError 1114] A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed`

It throws when I call teradatasql.connect(). Here is the full stack trace:

```
File "test.py", line 23, in <module>
    password = db_password
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\teradatasql\__init__.py", line 101, in __init__
    goside = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(sLibPathName)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 434, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 1114] A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed
```

I’ve tried manually loading the dll which teradatasql’s _*init*_ file is looking at, with

```
import ctypes
goside = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\teradatasql\teradatasql.dll')
```

And it throws the same error, although `ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary()` works for other .dll files on my machine.

Have tried reinstalling teradatasql and reverting to a previous version. Neither was helpful.

Bizarrely, the connection actually does work sometimes. The code which produced the stack trace above works when it’s in an .ipynb file rather than a .py. But I get the same error in .ipynb files with slightly different code.
Here’s my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import teradatasql 
from getpass import getpass 


db_password = getpass('Teradata password: ')


with teradatasql.connect(
    host = xxxx,
    user = xxxx,
    password = db_password
) as connect:
    query = '''
        …
    '''
    results = pd.read_sql(query, connect)
```

How do I deal with this dll issue and get the connection working reliably again?